# not able to install ruby-2.3.4

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.3

I am trying to install ruby-2.3.4 in my mac but without luck. Below is system's spec:

macOS Sierra
Version 10.12.6

I have ruby 2.0 by default and I managed to install ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin16]

Below is the error thrown when I do `rvm install ruby-2.3.4`

```
ruby-2.3.4 - #removing src/ruby-2.3.4..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.12/x86_64/ruby-2.3.4.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.3.4 - #downloading ruby-2.3.4, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.3.4 - #extracting ruby-2.3.4 to /Users/someuser/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.4.....
ruby-2.3.4 - #applying patch /Users/someuser/.rvm/patches/ruby/ruby_2_3_gcc7.patch.
ruby-2.3.4 - #applying patch /Users/someuser/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.3.4/fix_rb_thread_fd_close.patch.
ruby-2.3.4 - #applying patch /Users/someuser/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.3.4/random_c_using_NR_prefix.patch.
ruby-2.3.4 - #configuring...........................................................
ruby-2.3.4 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.3.4 - #compiling...........
Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /Users/someuser/.rvm/log/1528143943_ruby-2.3.4/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Any insight/idea what might be going on ?

Below are the bottom lines of the make.log file.

```
compiling enc/unicode.c
compiling enc/utf_8.c
compiling enc/trans/newline.c
1 warning generated.
linking miniruby
generating encdb.h
make: ./miniruby: Permission denied
make: ./miniruby: Permission denied
make: *** [.rbconfig.time] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [encdb.h] Error 1
++ return 2
```

Clearly, it's saying Permission denied. But I am not sure what kind of permission is it talking about ? I am able to install `ruby 2.5.1p57` without any problem.

Comment: `please read /Users/someuser/.rvm/log/1528143943_ruby-2.3.4/make.log` Do you have Xcode Command Line Tools installed?

Comment: Hey @tadman, I have pasted bottom few lines of make.log file above. Yes, I do have Xcode installed in my system. How does it help?

Comment: Xcode and Xcode Command-Line Tools are different. What does the output of `clang -v` say? If that doesn't exist: `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: @tadman, Below is the output : 

Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Comment: Looks like that part is installed correctly, which is good, but this permission denied thing looks like a permission error when installing with `rvm` which means you may need to `sudo` it or fix your permissions.

Comment: @tadman, running `rvm` with `sudo` gives me following error:  
  
`Checking requirements for osx_brew.  
Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.  
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all . 
build scripts full access to your system`.

Comment: The best option is to fix the permissions on your `~/.rvm` directory to ensure you can write to everything in there. I'm not sure how `brew` factors in here since you're asking about RVM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172546/discussion-between-chuchoo-and-tadman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rvm reload` did the magic. Running `rvm install ruby-2.3.4` after running `rvm reload` worked like a charm.

Comment: I have the same issue but this solution did not help me.

Comment: do you remember how you fixed it ?

Comment: @Shubhamkumar Please run this command 'rvm reload' before installing ruby.

That will solve your issue. Let me know if it doesn't

Comment: @Chuchoo no I remember that I did made it to reolad since it's in original answer. Now I have installed it via another means and not having trouble anymore.